# How to reload key from HSM by using openssl?

Tags: openssl, pki, hsm, openssl-engine

I'm using HSM via pkcs11 openssl engine. 
`ENGINE_load_private_key()` is used to load keys to use. 
It works fine, except after key pair generation:

After generating a new key-pair to HSM, `ENGINE_load_private_key()` still returns the old key.

Obviously later calls of `ENGINE_load_private_key()` does not read the key from HSM. Instead `ENGINE_load_private_key()` seems to return some cached value.

**Is there some way to force openssl to read the new key from the HSM, and not returning some old key that does not anymore exists in the HSM?**

This code piece was used to figure out the problem:

```
static void print_public_key_via_openssl( const char* name )
{
    ENGINE *e = ENGINE_by_id( "pkcs11");

    if ( e )
    {
        if ( ENGINE_init( e ) )
        {
            EVP_PKEY* key = ENGINE_load_private_key( e, name, NULL, NULL );
            if( key )
            {
                printf( "Public key:\n%s", public_key_to_str(key) );
                EVP_PKEY_free( key );
            }
            ENGINE_finish( e );
        }
        ENGINE_free( e );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ...

    // Load the key and print it to stdout
    print_public_key_via_openssl( "slot_1-label_Private02" );

    // Generate new key pair value. 
    system( "hsmtool --dump_key 2" );
    system( "hsmtool --gen_key 2" );
    system( "hsmtool --dump_key 2" );

    // Load the key and print it to stdout
    print_public_key_via_openssl( "slot_1-label_Private02" );
    ...
}
```

Result: key in the HSM did change, but openssl still returns the old key:

```
Public key:
    Public-Key: (256 bit)
    pub:
        04:da:6e:4a:5f:e8:80:e4:e8:07:b8:79:7c:62:f6:
        57:78:91:c4:42:89:13:da:72:61:e7:69:07:51:84:
        6a:a2:a2:74:7b:79:7b:31:74:1d:b0:74:16:d7:9f:
        fa:fd:2f:12:34:b9:80:06:16:84:c0:a3:0a:46:27:
        a5:90:30:38:c9
    ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    NIST CURVE: P-256

Key #2:
    X   : DA6E4A5FE880E4E807B8797C62F6577891C4428913DA7261E7690751846AA2A2
    Y   : 747B797B31741DB07416D79FFAFD2F1234B980061684C0A30A4627A5903038C9

Key #2:
    X   : D6321B2DAAC592DB1E06D43F674804D0107252012BBDD214A7BB519109DD5D6E
    Y   : 0315E667625CBECA08A1D61BD0087D20D888A41AAE0E28D8789B8BDC8F6D09FF

Public key:
    Public-Key: (256 bit)
    pub:
        04:da:6e:4a:5f:e8:80:e4:e8:07:b8:79:7c:62:f6:
        57:78:91:c4:42:89:13:da:72:61:e7:69:07:51:84:
        6a:a2:a2:74:7b:79:7b:31:74:1d:b0:74:16:d7:9f:
        fa:fd:2f:12:34:b9:80:06:16:84:c0:a3:0a:46:27:
        a5:90:30:38:c9
    ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    NIST CURVE: P-256
```

Several programs will use the keypair from the HSM. And Those programs also uses other key pairs actively for TLS. So, restarting a process is not solution.

Comment: Can you verify whether the new key is in the same slot and does override the old one or not?

Comment: Yes, the new key is generated over the old key in HSM. That is verified.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is to call ENGINE_cleanup(), ENGINE_finish() and ENGINE_init() after key generation and see if it loads the new key or not

Comment: Yes, that works. I already implement crazy workaround, that uses the clean-up and re-opening of openssl/crypto. The workaround is slow and it affects to existing TLS connections (which are using other key-pairs). But maybe we need to live with that..

Comment: Why do you map a different key over another key in the first place? Create a new one with a new label, then destroy the old one when required. That way you've got more control. Usually you can also setup a counter in a HSM, by the way.